# Library missing with GoMobile build

Tags: go, gomobile, gomobile-android

I get the following error while trying to build with Go mobile, fresh install with fresh NDK install. ANDROID_NDK_HOME is set, but it seems to not find a particular library.

Running on Mac.

```
gomobile: /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm /var/folders/zc/4fqpckd56nz59k253rcj66380000gn/T/gomobile-work-456128244/lib/armeabi-v7a/libbasic.so: fork/exec /Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: no such file or directory
```

Comment: go-mobile is easy to set up and get working on linux, from your error looks like you may be on windows or mac, suggest you build with docker or a linux vm